# Better way to group objects from Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a CRUD api for a post processing tool. I have some data that have a structure of:

```
{
  _date: '3/19/2021',
  monitor: 'metric1',
  project: 'bluejays',
  id1: 'test-pmon-2',
  voltageCondition: 'HV',
  testData: [],
  id: null
}
```

So previous methods I had was I would maintain a separate MongoDB collection which stored high level data of jobs that are stored and these would displayed. This method worked however I would like just one collection for this group of data.

My current method iterates through all objects in the query. The query is relatively small and I set a limit on the return so there is no names really of speed and memory allocation. However, I would like to dev up a more efficient method. This is my current method:

```
jobHeaderList_2 = [];
queriedData.forEach(doc => {
    if (jobHeaderList_2.length == 0) {
        jobHeaderList_2.push({
            id1: doc.id1,
            project: doc.project,
            monitor: [doc.monitor],
            date: doc._date
        })
    }
    else {
        let index = jobHeaderList_2.map(obj => {
            return obj.id1;
        }).indexOf(doc.id1);

        if (index == -1) {
            jobHeaderList_2.push({
                id1: doc.id1,
                project: doc.projectId,
                monitor: [doc.monitor],
                date: doc._date
            })
        }
        else if (jobHeaderList_2[index].monitor.includes(doc.monitor) == false) {
            jobHeaderList_2[index].monitor.push(doc.monitor);
        }
    }
});
```

And this works fine, but I would like someone who is more experienced who can maybe help me with a better method of doing this. Basically, I want to group all objects with the same id1 into a single object that stores the monitor values in an array.

I do not want to change the data structure because it's efficient for the plotting that occurs elsewhere in the application.

Comment: How is `jobHeaderList_2` initialised? Is it empty when the loop starts? Is `queriedData` an array, or is it some Mongo query object?

Comment: queriedData is is an array of objects. jobHeaderList_2 is init as an empty array

Comment: You received several answers. Could you give feed-back on them, or mark an answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using vanilla JavaScript, using an ES6 map to key the data by id.

```
let map = new Map(queriedData.map(doc => [doc.id, {
    id1: doc.id1,
    project: doc.projectId,
    monitor: [],
    date: doc._date
}]));

for (let {id, monitor} of queriedData) map.get(id).monitor.push(monitor);

let jobHeaderList_2 = [...map.values()];
```

Comment: Hi @trincot. Thanks for the response. I havent seen this method of constructing objects with map. Could you point me to a reference so I can read up on it? Implementing this blindly at the moment.

Comment: You can find it in the MDN documentation on the [Map() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) under the Parameters heading. [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (lowercase) returns an array, here in the format that this constructor can deal with. The actual objects are constructed with a simple object literal. So `doc.id` is the first value of a pair, and the object is the second in that pair. The `Map` constructor uses those pairs to define the key/values for it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using vanilla Javascript that doesn't require any new knowledge:

```js
const queriedData = [
  {
    _date: '3/19/2021',
    monitor: 'metric1',
    project: 'bluejays',
    id1: 'test-pmon-2',
    voltageCondition: 'HV',
    testData: [],
    id: null,
  },
  {
    _date: '3/20/2021',
    monitor: 'metric2',
    project: 'yellowjays',
    id1: 'test-pmon-2',
    voltageCondition: 'HV',
    testData: [],
    id: null,
  },
  {
    _date: '3/21/2021',
    monitor: 'metric3',
    project: 'orangejays',
    id1: 'test-pmon-3',
    voltageCondition: 'HV',
    testData: [],
    id: null,
  },
]

function accumulateMonitor(queriedData) {
  const jobHeaderList_2 = []
  const indexById = {}

  queriedData.forEach((doc) => {
    const index = indexById[doc.id1]
    if (index === undefined) {
      indexById[doc.id1] = jobHeaderList_2.length
      jobHeaderList_2.push({
        id1: doc.id1,
        project: doc.project,
        monitor: [doc.monitor],
        date: doc._date,
      })
    } else {
      const jobHeader = jobHeaderList_2[index]
      jobHeader.monitor.push(doc.monitor)
    }
  })

  return jobHeaderList_2
}

console.log(accumulateMonitor(queriedData))

/*
[
  {
    id1: 'test-pmon-2',
    project: 'bluejays',
    monitor: [ 'metric1', 'metric2' ],
    date: '3/19/2021'
  },
  {
    id1: 'test-pmon-3',
    project: 'orangejays',
    monitor: [ 'metric3' ],
    date: '3/21/2021'
  }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have figured out an answer using pipelining!

I used the `$group` filter stage, `$addToSet` and `$addFields` operator.

```
const test1 = await pmon.aggregate([
            {
                $group:{
                _id:"$id1",
                monitor:{
                    $addToSet: "$monitor"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields:{
                    id1:"$_id"
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Essentially works as follows:

- group all elements based on id1
- add the monitor values using `$addToSet`
- finally, added an id1 field back after using this as the value for the _id key.